# Android Gradle Build is showing error String types not allowed (at 'userName' with value '')

Tags: java, android

My Android Gradle is showing error when trying to run my app. It's showing

```
String types not allowed (at 'userName' with value '')
```

Here is gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.natol.grade12app"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

And the top level gradle code is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Strings XML file looks like this

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Grade 12</string>
    <string name="insert_reg_no">Your Reg No.</string>
    <string name="check_me">Check me!</string>
    <string name="insert_your_reg_no">Insert your reg no</string>
    <string name="score">Score</string>
    <string name="category">Category</string>
    <string name="not_released">Not released</string>
    <string name="institute">Institute</string>
    <string name="loading">Loading...</string>
    <string name="userName">User Name</string>
    <string name="field_selected">Feild</string>
    <string name="full_name">Full name</string>
    <string name="natural">Natural</string>
    <string name="school">School</string>
    <string name="male">Male</string>
</resources>
```

The layout TextView wich uses this string looks like this

```
-----------
------
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/userName"
                android:id="@+id/userName" />
---------
--------
```

I don't know what to do. Can any one give hint here?

Comment: Post your gradle file (you have typo on your message)

Comment: I have updated the question with my gradle file....check it out

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is on the app gradle and not in the top level gradle?

Comment: The problem can be also in a XML file

Comment: i couldn't find problem with app gradle..I have attached the top level gradle...

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution....
The problem was with me, in the colors.xml my looks like this

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#1b5e79</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#300F50</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="userName"></color>
</resources>
```

And i deleted the last line in my resource tag

```
<color name="userName"></color>
```

And its working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML layout files. You probably forget a "+" in your id attribute

Comment: post the xml layout file that use the <string name="user_Name">User Name</string>

Comment: The key for this string used to be name="userName" ...in my layout XML file I have deleted the TextView wich uses this string...

Comment: I have updated to what used to looks like when the problem started...also I have published the layout which uses  the string

Comment: I just found where the problem was as you have told me...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing the id to something different `@+id/user` ?